# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Module_model::active()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with my cms; when I want to use my bugtracker, I get this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Module_model::active() in C:\wamp\www\CI\application\controllers\Support.php on line 107
>   A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to undefined method Module_model::active()
>
> Filename: controllers/Support.php
>
> Line Number: 107

This is the code :

```html
public function bugtracker()
 {
  $this->load->model('CMS_model', 'CMSManager');
  if($this->session->has_userdata('guid') || $this->ModuleManager->active(23) != TRUE){
   $data['account'] = $this->AccountManager->info('guid', $this->session->userdata('guid'));
  }
  else{
   $data = array();
  }
  $data['bugtrackers'] = $this->CMSManager->bugtrackers();
  $this->layout->view('support/bugtracker', $data);
  foreach($data['bugtrackers'] as $bugtracker){
   if(isset($_POST['vote'])){
    if(!$this->session->has_userdata('guid')){
     redirect('home/');
    }
    else{
     $this->CMSManager->add_vote($bugtracker->id, $bugtracker->vote_account.$data['account']->guid.'|', $bugtracker->vote + 1);
     $this->message->alert('1', 'Vote accepté, redirection en cours...', site_url('support/bugtracker'), '3');
    }
   }
  }
  if(isset($_POST['post'])){
   if(!$this->session->has_userdata('guid')){
    redirect('home/');
   }
   else{
    $title = post($this->input->post('title'));
    $content = post(nl2br($this->input->post('content')));
    if(empty($title) || empty($content)){
     $this->message->alert('2', 'Champs vides.', site_url('support/bugtracker'), '3');
    }
    elseif(strlen($title) > 50 || strlen($title) < 5){
     $this->message->alert('2', 'La longueur de votre titre est incorrect.', site_url('support/bugtracker'), '3');
    }
    elseif(strlen($content) < 10){
     $this->message->alert('2', 'La longueur de votre report est incorrect.', site_url('support/bugtracker'), '3');
    }
    else{
     $this->CMSManager->add_bug($data['account']->guid, $title, $data['account']->guid.'|', $content);
     $this->message->alert('1', 'Bug publié, redirection en cours...', site_url('support/bugtracker'), '3');
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: It's complicated issue, you probably inherited code and you don't know exactly where you are. I don't see any call to static method: `Module_model::active()`, which line is line no. 107? Maybe `if($this->session->has_userdata('guid') || $this->ModuleManager->active(23) != TRUE){` ? Removing static from function also is not the solution, earlier software maker had intentions, that you should research. Try to add more details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error of undefined variable might be due to the `;` that you have after `foreach`. Please remove the `;` after foreach & then check again.

Comment: No problem. It happens to all of us.